# Can a Lightning Component be Deleted?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Deleting them from developer console (SHIFT+DELETE) doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone been successful at doing this?

Answer (score 6):

You can delete the Lightning component from Developer console as follow
[image]

You can Delete the Lightning component from Eclipse as follow
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can do this using CTRL+Delete.

Also under file there is option for Delete Thats also works. You can try any option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this via HaoIDE: https://github.com/xjsender/haoide which is via metadata API or tooling API . So I think both force.com IDE with Eclipse and Mavensmate can do the same thing.